# Breaking an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, break

Only been learning front end development for 10 weeks so please be kind! I'm trying to return objects at index 0 - 3 (out of 4) from a weather api. I only want to return the first 4 days from a 5 day forecast.

I've been reading about breaking the for loop with 'break', I had the idea to say that if i is equal to 3 then to break the loop but when I do that it doesn't run anymore of my code. I'm assuming I can't run one if statement directly after the first? When I add the break statement in, nothing displays on screen.

```
$.ajax({
      url: forecast,
      method: "GET",
      }).then(function(response) { 
         console.log(response)
         $('#days').empty()
         var weatherArray = response.list; 
         for (var i = 0; i <weatherArray.length; i++) {
           if (weatherArray.length === 3) {
            break;
                   
          console.log(weatherArray[i]);
          if (weatherArray[i].dt_txt.split(' ')[1] === '12:00:00') {
               var cityMain = $('<div>');
               cityMain.addClass('col-lg-2 col-md-6 mb-2 forecast-card>');
               var date = $("<h5>").text(response.list[i].dt_txt.split(" ")[0]);
               var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + weatherArray[i].weather[0].icon + '.png');
               var minTemp = $('<p>').text('Min Temperature: ' + weatherArray[i].main.temp_min + '°C');  
               var maxTemp = $('<p>').text('Max Temperature : ' + weatherArray[i].main.temp_max + '°C');                               
               cityMain.append(date).append(image).append(minTemp).append(maxTemp)
               
               $('#days').append(cityMain);
```

Comment: Why not `for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++)` without any break?

Comment: you are checking for array length (`if (weatherArray.length === 3)`), which is the same for each iteration through that array. But also, the curly braces are not closed behind the `break`, so there is code that never gets executed.

Comment: *it doesn't run anymore of my code* - it doesn't run any code *within the for loop* and *after the break* - that's correct, that's what break does - it exits the `for` loop when the condition hits.  In your case, you've got the right idea, **just the wrong condition**:   should be: `if (i === 3) break;`  (or, more robustly, `if (i>=3) break;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.

You can modify the for loop to only look at the first 0-3 elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
```

If you want to use a `break` statement be careful of how you use it. As written You're looking at the length of the raw weatherArray array which never changes. You could modify it to look at the current array index.

```
           if (i === 3) {
            break;
```

However, it's best to use greater than and less than conditions in loops to make sure you catch all out-of-range conditions

```
           if (i >= 3) {
            break;
```

Finally, you're missing a close brace immediately after the `break` statement, which is making your code execute only when the the weatherData array has length 3.